# How to set up compile library in android studio. LOMBOK

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, lombok

Help me to set up comile dependencies in Android Studio in build.gradle.
I mean that they not include into final APK.

this build.gradle works fine but i don't need

> lombok

library in apk in runtime;

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.2' }
```

And may be its possible to setup in global build.gradle file for all projects?

Comment: "CLOSED" If you mean solved, just accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve this issue by changing `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in gradle folder.
Now it looks like this:

```
#Sat Jan 25 02:59:06 EET 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

and in main `build.gradle` file i can wrote this for lombok

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'android'

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 10
            targetSdkVersion 16
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                runProguard false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
        provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.2'
    }
}
```

Now in sub projects i don't need write many params for plugins or repositories and provided method works pretty fine.

Comment: You've just made lombok "provided", that's why you solved it.

Answer (score 13):

With Android Studio 1.1.0, I couldn't find a consolidated set of instructions for adding Lombok that worked for me. That includes Lombok's own setup page: http://projectlombok.org/setup/android.html

Here's everything I had to do to get it working (on OS X):

- Install Lombok plugin in Android Studio

  - Android Studio > Preferences > Plugins
  - Click on `Browse repositories...`
  - Search for Lombok Plugin
  - Click on `Install plugin`
  - Restart Android Studio
- Add to the android/dependencies block in app/build.gradle: `provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.2'`

  - See [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22lombok%22) for latest version, as lombok's instructions don't update as they release new versions
  - I assume the `subprojects` approach in build.gradle in the project root (from Олександр Самсонов's answer) works also, but it appears that requires moving the configuration from app/build.gradle (you aren't allowed to further extend the configuration in the subprojects). I didn't want to move the entire android configuration, so I kept it in the app/build.gradle instead.
- Create a `lombok.config` file in the root of the project containing two lines:
  `lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true`
  `lombok.addGeneratedAnnotation = false`

Answer (score 6):

The ability to do this was just added to the v0.8 Android-Gradle plugin, which you can use if you're running Android Studio 0.4.3 (which is available on the canary update channel).

It's mentioned in the [release notes](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio043released) and a [thread on the adt-dev mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/KNjKJet4VOk)

You specify it like this:

```
dependencies {
    provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.2'
}
```

I've filed bug https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65216 to request the ability to edit this through the **Dependencies** panel in the **Project Structure** dialog; for the moment you have to edit your **build.gradle** file by hand to use this.

As for whether you can put it in the top-level **build.gradle** file to have it apply to all modules, I'm not certain. I tried putting it in the `allprojects` block, but Gradle told me that the default dependency handler didn't know what to do with it. So I'm guessing no, but if I get other information, I'll update this answer.

Comment: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'start.android'.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.provided() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.2]

Comment: For all projects I found `subprojects { apply plugin: 'android' }`

Comment: You get this DefaultDependencyHanlder exception if you try to put it in your top-level build.gradle file; if you put it in the build file for individual modules that need it, it should work.

Comment: thanks for help but that not work until i change gradle properties file and version of gradle.

Now all works in global build file.

Answer (score 3):

For **Android Studio**

1. Go to File > Settings > Plugins
2. Click on "Browse repositories..."
3. Search for "Lombok Plugin"
4. Click on "Install plugin"
5. Restart Android Studio