# Are there reasons not to use lombok with android studio

Tags: java, android, lombok

Does anyone know of any reason to not use lombok with android studio? I have POJOs with 60 fields and many important methods. I would rather not litter the files with accessors. My option is to declare the fields public or use lombok. I know how to set it up ([How to set up compile library in android studio. LOMBOK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344692/how-to-set-up-compile-library-in-android-studio-lombok)). But I don’t want to publish my app and then find out it does not work with some android device simply because of lombok. I am coding agains API-14 and up. Thanks. Also right now I am compiling against API-23, and will keep compiling against whatever is latest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lombok generates ordinary Java code at compile time, and then it's essentially identical to what your IDE would generate. The Android toolchain won't even know the difference.