# How to use lombok plugin in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, lombok

I installed *lombok* from *'Preferences -> Plugin'*, but it's not working when I am trying to generate Getter & Setter. My code doesn't recognize it.

Is there anyone having idea how to setup lombok and use it to generate getter & setter annotation?

Comment: Did you try this [instructions](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android.html)? This post can help you also: [How to set up compile library in android studio. LOMBOK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21344692/how-to-set-up-compile-library-in-android-studio-lombok)

Comment: Thanks Alex! It worked.
I was using provider with 1.12.6 plugin as mentioned in project lombok, but it worked with 1.16.2 version, which I think was the problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need not only to install `Lombok Plugin`, but also add dependency to `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies{
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.12' //or v. 1.16.2 in your case.
}
```

More info on [official guide](https://projectlombok.org/setup/android.html).

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29663100/3810333) with instructions.

Answer (score 18):

There are so many posts on this subject its bewildering.
I am on the following:
[image] 
[image] [image][image]
And having torn most of my hair out, trying to figure out
what the heck is going on with gradle top level and project level, 
THE ONLY COMBINATION that worked for me was this:
[image]`implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.0'
 annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.0'`[image]`classpath 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.0'`
And here is the proof:[image]
My god is it really this complicated to do something this simple.

Comment: Please note, I now get this: Caused by: Caused by: 
    com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\kambiz\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.projectlombok\lombok\1.18.0\c4647d46f0742746ac07ce4abeeee9b2fb18d147\lombok-1.18.0.jar ...therefore the above answer has an issue. Sorry, but I just tried to build the project and I get the error.

Comment: ...I tried everything I know...it compiles but it does not build....even tried the lombok plugin for gradle. Its a nightmare. Sorry, I did my best.

Comment: Clean your project before build

Answer (score 7):

There's a section related to this on official docs: https://projectlombok.org/setup/android

Follow the previous instructions (Gradle). In addition to setting up your gradle project correctly, you need to add the Lombok IntelliJ plugin to add lombok support to Android Studio:

Go to File > Settings > Plugins
Click on Browse repositories...
Search for Lombok Plugin
Click on Install plugin
Restart Android Studio
Modify your application's dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.22'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.22'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case be aware that if your project have mixed Kotlin and Java code - you can't use lombok normal way for now.

Based on this issue: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/1169

**EDIT:**

from kotlin 1.7.20 with K2 compiler it is possible withot concerns.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew1720.html#support-for-kotlin-k2-compiler-plugins

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
    dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Lombok is not available for most recent Android Studio which is Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2

I tied install it manually from official site:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/versions

It partially helped but completely break IDE indexing so when you open source it can't complete Analyzing... stage and you can't navigate or get code suggestions.

I end up with Lombok plugin version from this site and it seems works now:

https://github.com/sgpublic/lombok-plugin-repository

Hope official support will fix the problem soon.